# Auto calculate some Input fields javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to make a product calculator, so I need to automatically calculate some input fields

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="Calculator">
<div id="TileAdhesive_Calculator" class="calculatorContainer">
    <div id="select">
        <label for="inp_LevellingDepth">Bed thickness mm</label>
        <input id="inp_LevellingDepth" type="number" value="1" onChange="calculate();" onkeyup="calculate();" >
        <label for="inp_LevellingArea">Area to be covered in m²</label>
        <input id="inp_LevellingArea" type="number" onChange="calculate();" onkeyup="calculate();">
    </div>      
    <div id="LevellingResults" class="calculatorResult">
        <h3 class="section-headline">Resultat</h3>          
        <h4>The number of kg required.</h4>
        <p><span id="LevellingRequirement"></span></p>
        <p><input id="totat_kg" type="text" name="total_kilo" onkeyup="calculate_bags();"/></p>
        <h4>The number of units required for your project <span id="LevellingPackSize"></span> kg sækker, der kræves til dit projekt.</h4>
        <p><span id="LevellingBagsRequired"></span></p>
        <p><input id="total_bags" type="text" name="total_bags" onkeyup="calculate_bags();"/></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript looks like this:

```
<script>
calculate = function()
{
    var coverage_product = document.getElementById('inp_coverage_product').value;
    var prod_depth = document.getElementById('inp_LevellingDepth').value;
    var prod_area = document.getElementById('inp_LevellingArea').value; 
    document.getElementById('totat_kg').value = coverage_product * prod_depth * prod_area;

}

calculate_bags = function()
{
    var totat_kg = document.getElementById('totat_kg').value;
    var packSize_prod = document.getElementById('inp_packSize_product').value;
    document.getElementById('total_bags').value = totat_kg / packSize_prod;

}
```

My problem is the input "The number of units required for your project" does not automatically get calculated.

Can someone help me?

JSFiddle link her: https://jsfiddle.net/simondevs/1nzdkhem/9/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) *<<...the input "The number of units required for your project" does not autmaticly get calculated.>>* Nothing in the code is doing anything to update the the `span` with `id="LevellingPackSize"`. Your best bet is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck, post a [mcve] and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Just call `calculate_bags()` after the calculations inside the `calculate` function

Answer (score 0):

put everything into calculate like:

```
calculate = function() {
    var coverage_product = document.getElementById('inp_coverage_product').value;
    var prod_depth = document.getElementById('inp_LevellingDepth').value;
    var prod_area = document.getElementById('inp_LevellingArea').value; 
    document.getElementById('totat_kg').value = coverage_product * prod_depth * prod_area;
    var totat_kg = document.getElementById('totat_kg').value;
    var packSize_prod = document.getElementById('inp_packSize_product').value;
    document.getElementById('total_bags').value = totat_kg / packSize_prod;
}
```

total_bags el element is update on calculate_bags(), which is fired when input of either `The number of kg required.` or `The number of units required for your project` is changed, which is not desired behavior if I understood correctly. onkeyup="calculate_bags();" handlers seem obsolete.

Can downvoters elaborate, please?

https://jsfiddle.net/1nzdkhem/29/

Comment: How do i do so I only get 2 decimals ?

Comment: document.getElementById('total_bags').value = totat_kg.toFixed(2);

Answer (score 0):

It will be calculated once you type into either the "totat_kg" or "total_bags" box. That's because the calculate_bags() function is triggered by the "keyup" event on those fields, whereas a "keyup" on the other two fields triggers the "calculate()" function.

Assuming you want it to be calculated on any input, then just add a call

```
calculate_bags();
```

as the last line of the calculate function.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/simondevs/1nzdkhem/9/